# parallelizing code with python pathos multiprocessing in docker

Tags: python, docker, multiprocessing, pathos, process-pool

I am parallizing code across 30 CPUs and confirmed that outside a container this works fine using the python library 'pathos'.

```
pool = ProcessPool(nodes=30)
results = pool.map(func_that_needs_to_run_in_parallel, range(30))
pool.close()
pool.join()

results_df = pd.concat(results)
```

However, it doesn't work while running the code as part of a Flask app in a Docker container. I have three containers:

- flask app,
- redis which I use to offload all the heavy processing to a worker process,
- the worker process.

The code for the worker process can be summarised as:

```
#some code that needs to be run on only one cpu
#the above 'ProcessPool' code snippet for one particularly resource-intensive task
#some code that needs to be run on only one cpu
```

When I run the app, the parallelization part of the code in the worker container never uses more than 4 cpus. I confirmed this in docker stats and `htop`. There are no cpu usage limits on the containers in the docker-compose yaml file.

`htop` shows that the code runs on only 4 cpus at any one time but it actually randomly switches which cpus its using during the task, thus the worker container can access all 48 cpus.

**Summary**: Running the app with this multiprocessing code is helpful but there is a ceiling on CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

Early docker literature (2016) suggested one container per CPU, which is clearly not the case. The idea is to configure this at run time, in the same way you assign memory,

```
docker run -it --cpus="30" debian /bin/bash
```

The  docker container resource allocation I found useful, [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/resource_constraints/#cpu)

---

If `pathos` is the issue why not switch to the`multiprocessor.Pool()` library via  `apply`, `map_async`, or `imap` methods?

Comment: An alternative to doing this configuration at run-time is to put all of these config options in a docker compose file. That is the approach I was using when I claimed 30 cpus are available to the application. I suspect the problem is with the library 'pathos'

Comment: Thanks,its an interesting possibility. I've put an alternative suggestion above